# ASP.NET Application Gets Slower Over Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis

I'm running a .NET C# (4.5) web forms application and on our production server, the application gets slower and slower for everyone over time until about an hour where it becomes pretty much unusable and we just restart the server.

It works perfectly fine on my local machine. Never gets slower at all. So I'm trying to think of what would be different.

My local machine connect to the same database. There's also some active directory things being used for logins but that also connects to the same place on both my local and production environments.

I have debug off in the web.config. I've also looked up pretty much any other solutions and haven't had luck.

I did see some stuff about viewstates building up with ajax requests. I do have a page with updatepanels that are refreshing every few seconds, but I'm confused as to why the production server would be getting slower over time with this and not my local machine testing.

There's only about 10 people using the application at the moment also. Any ideas?

Comment: do you use Linq, in your solution?

Comment: This could be due to memory leaks, it might be worth profiling memory usage for those. Event subscribers can be a likely culprit for MLs in production which you don't get on your dev machine. Usually takes longer than an hour to become a real problem, though.

Comment: It may be worth profiling your application (if this is possible in production) to narrow down the problem (i.e. SQL Server profiling, IIS tracing/request logging). Perhaps also client side profiling. Tools such as RedGate's ANTS profiler could also -conceivably- be used in production (it is very good for this purpose). In an ideal world you wouldn't be profiling production apps due to the overhead, but it sounds like you don't have much to lose...

Comment: @johnjerrico 
 
Yeah I'm using LINQ on some stuff for lists. var stores = from item in LB_Stores.Items.OfType<ListItem>() where item.Selected select item.Value;

Comment: It is likely a memory leak or un-optimized (un-indexed tables) Queries (stored Procedures).
If your app allows sending different parameters ranges from different users there are probably users that are requesting very big ranges of Data.  
(when you say you restart the server) did you try just restarting the App-Pool (Presumably you are using a dedicated App-pool ). Check to see the resource use for the Data Base server

Comment: By restart I mean the whole server. Restarting app pool didn't really do anything to help. Database is on a completely separate server though. After the work day ended and people stopped using the application speeds went back to normal. So it seems the issue builds up only as people are actively using it. (So probably not a memory leak since it gets fast again when nobody is using it right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing a bunch of updatepanels every few seconds is not a good idea pretty much. I was able to optimize things here and there but in the end it was the auto refreshing that was slowing things down. Completely reprogrammed using signalr to grab updates and now it's very fast.

Comment: Also make sure database tables are properly indexed